# Dataframe column like groupby but not how to do it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here is a sample dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': ['101', '101', '101', '105', '105'], 
     'qty': [10, 15, 20, 50, 55],
    }
df31 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df31

    id  qty
0   101 10
1   101 15
2   101 20
3   105 50
4   105 55
```

How to get results like this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide context on why you need it like this. Is this just for displaying?

Comment: Is the id-column sorted?

Comment: @mcsoini yes, and to_dict('records') for api and displaying in website

Comment: @timgeb yes id-column is sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your desired output consist of empty strings.

You can use `shift` to check equality of a value with it's previous value and assign back `''` if condition is met:

```
df31['id'] = np.where(df31['id'].shift() == df31['id'],'',df31['id'])
```

---

```
>>> print(df31)

    id  qty
0   101 10
1       15
2       20
3   105 50
4       55

>>> print(df31.to_dict('records'))

 [{'id': '101', 'qty': 10},
 {'id': '', 'qty': 15},
 {'id': '', 'qty': 20},
 {'id': '105', 'qty': 50},
 {'id': '', 'qty': 55}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the id-column is sorted:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].drop_duplicates().reindex(df.index, fill_value='')
```